# Mobile advertising company working with admob house ads

Tags: android, sdk, admob, mopub

I'm currently using admob sdk to monetize my apps.
I recently wanted to earn more, and I found a french company. So I created a House ad, from the admob website to relay their ads on my apps. 
But now I want to expend it to other countries.
I found a lot of companies but they are all using their own sdk... (mobfox,mopub,etc...)
So did you know any that are providing a banner picture and a direct link to the ad in order to make it work with the admob house ads ?